# Adding URL path to webform stops contact prefill - why?

Tags: webform-civicrm, urls, paths

[image]I added a URL path to a working Drupal webform, and emailed users were given this link to the webform (which went through Civimail) : 
https://www.example.org/christmasconnection?cid1={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}.  
Later I
found that the existing contact wasn't being prefilled.  Eventually I figured it was this change that had caused the problem.  When I changed the link back to the usual Drupal format with 'node':

https://www.example.org/node/82?cid1={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum} 
the contact prefill worked.  Why is this?  We will now email users to give them the working link, but is there a way of fixing this so either works?  Is this a bug or a 'feature'! (screenshot added)

Comment: Are you using URL Alias (Pathauto module) or URL Redirect module or another module?

Comment: I have neither module installed. In Drupal's 'URL Aliases' the path 'christmasconnection' is an alias for node/82 - is that relevant?

Comment: We use URL aliases all the time. Could it be a caching issue?

Comment: The problem is rock solid, so I don't think it can be caching.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take out CiviMail from the equation -> are you able to do this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, not able to do exactly that - this is Drupal 7 and Civi at 5.28.3.  I can only type in a URL path setting - screenshot added to original question

Comment: Ok so I mean - can you view the form and is it handling the arguments properly -> with the alias -> like I have in my screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I've added a URL alias and it works fine - in fact I've left it there as we already sent an email to users with the link using that URL - so they might still try it. It works but doesn't fill the existing contact. Your screen (Drupal 8?) just looks different to mine.

Comment: I am in Drupal 7 (and use links to prefilled webforms with aliases regularly) my screenshot looks the same as Karin's with the Generate automatic URL alias checkbox. But I am using Pathauto. Perhaps that's the difference?